# Issue with Context when trying to create an instance of custom adapter class

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'm new to android and trying to create a custom array adapter which I have called NewsStoryAdapter. When I try to create an instance of the adapter [This error dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN6HJ.png) occurs.
There seems to be a problem with the way I am getting context however i'm not sure how to fix this.

below are the import statements as well as the constructor for the custom NewsAdater class

```
package com.example.android.newsstand;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsStory> {
    public NewsAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<NewsStory> stories) {
        super(context, 0, stories);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your MainActivity doesn't extend Activity.  This means it can't be passed into a method that requires an Activity